# How would I handle a change of view with Core Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have a Core Bluetooth macOS app with a CBCentralManager controlling the bluetooth communication. I have a discovery view that will segue to a data display view once the desired device is found. However, I don't want to start over with bluetooth communication when I change view controllers. The CBCentralManager is in the discovery view controller; will I lose my bluetooth connections if I make another CBCentralManager in the data view? Could I pass the CBCentralManager through the segue?

Comment: I generally put the Bluetooth code in its own object and use `NSNotificstion` and/or delegation to have that object interact with the rest of the application. You can then pass a reference to this "manager" object as required.

Comment: @paulw11 Initially tried that but it got messy chaining delegation from the core Bluetooth class to the manager class to the view controller class. Would passing it through prepareForSegue disrupt its function?

Comment: I would use `NSNotification` rather than delegation. Have your Bluetooth manager class expose various properties (discovered devices, connected devices etc) and have it send messages on state change (data received, connecte,device discovered etc)